# SQL - Filter and group based on column value

Tags: sql, string, text, filter, group

I have the below table.

```
Code     Status    
1        Noaudit/One  
1        Audit/One      
1        Audit/Two      
2        Noaudit/One
2        Noaudit/Two
3        Audit/One
3        Audit/Two
```

This is the desired output result:

```
Code     Status      
1        Audit/One      
1        Audit/Two
2        Noaudit/One
2        Noaudit/Two
3        Audit/One
3        Audit/Two
```

Basically, if a code has status of audit and Noaudit only audit records should be displayed. If the code has only Noaudit records all the Noaudit records should be displayed. Thanks in advance.

I tried grouping by and then applying the filter but it did not work.

Comment: What is the actual structure of your table?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select code, sum(case when t.status like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) as a
  from t 
  group by code
) x on x.code = t.code
where x.a > 0 and t.status like 'A%'
   or x.a = 0 and t.status like 'N%'
```

**Note**: The OP doesn't clearly define the case for only-audits, but the included result implies they should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select Code, Status
from
(
 select *, 
    count(case when Status like 'Audit%' then 1 end) over (partition by Code) as Audit
 from table_name
) T
where Status like 'Audit%' or Audit=0
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/smBLK_3X).

Comment: Using window functions can actually be faster than my solution. Great thinking.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thank you, and your solution is more general one and will work of DBMS that don't support window functions. (since the OP didn't tag his DBMS)